# elements not being written into array in java

Tags: java, arrays

So I've written a programme used to solve a concrete equation having been given one parameter int n. The code I have is:

```
 static double getSolution1(int n)
{
    double [] a = new double[n+1];
    a[0] =-1;
    for (int i = 1; i < n+1; i++)
    {
        a[i] = a[i-1] * ( ( 2 / ( 3 * n ) ) * Math.cos(2 * a[i-1]) );
    }
    return a[n];
}
```

As far as I can tell, the code works fine and should be filling in the various parts of the array. But that's not happening, apart from a[0] = -1 that I have told the programme, it is treating all other entries as 0 as though it has not undergone the loop. Using a debug, that's the only problem I can really find. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 / 3 *n would give you zero, use all floats or doubles like 2.0f 3.0f

Comment: Sorry can you explain a little bit more please?

Comment: when u use integers like 2 /3 the result is zero, so all your array elenments are being multiplied by zero. to prevent this use 2.0f / 3.0f which would give float values

Answer (score 0):

The "2 / ( 3 * n )" is being evaluated as **int**; and it works out as 0.

To fix, change it to "2.0 / (3.0 * n)"

Answer (score 0):

As Pulkit said, 2/3 *n yields zero.  Why?

Integer division will always round down your result to the nearest whole number.  So:

```
2 / 3 = .666
floor(.666) = 0
```

To prevent this, you can add `f` to the end of 2 or 3.  That'll cause the operation to evaluate as a float rather than an integer, avoiding the rounding.

```
2f / 3f
```

You can also add `d` to 2 or 3.  That'll cause the operation to evaluate as a double rather than an integer.

```
2d / 3d
```

Answer (score 0):

the expression ( 2 / ( 3 * n ) return an integer type. so for every number between 1 and 0, int type will be 0. what you can do is to let compiler treats 2 and 3 as float type or double type. you can use 2.0 instead of 2. or 3.0 instead of 3